# Use nodejs module in external javascript from the public folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I included a module in my js file. Now i defined a button in a ejs file, which calls a function in an external js file from the public folder. How can i use the module in this function?

I tried to pass the module as a parameter, but i didn´t work. Is this even the right way to use this module in my external file?

the route js file

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var R = require("r-integration");

/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("Upload", { title: "Upload", para: R });
});

module.exports = router;
```

my ejs file with the button which calls the function `loadScript()`
Here i also tried to pass the paramter `para` to the const `rModule`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onClick="loadScript()">Test Skript</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    const rModule = para;
  </script>
  <script src="/javascripts/rScriptTest.js"></script>
</html>
```

the external js file from the public folder.
But here it says, that rModule is not defined.

```
function loadScript() {
  let result = rModule.executeRScript("./RScripts/test.r");
  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a function though an EJS template. It won't serialize cleanly.

You need:

- A JS script/module that will run on a browser
- A URL for that file (usually provided with [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html))

You fail at the first hurdle. The [module you are trying to use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/r-integration) describes itself thus:

> This is the R-integration API which allows you to execute arbitrary R commands or scripts directly from the node JS environment. This integration works on Windows and GNU/Linux based systems and uses system calls to access the R binary.

There is no way that it is going to achieve that without using Node.js-specific APIs that are not available in the browser.

You could [write a web service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/build-web-api-nodejs-express/) in Node.js and interact with it using [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead.

Comment: So i can make this web service to interact with the r-integration module in my javascript file?

Comment: You make it in your Node.js JS files and not in your browser JS files.

Comment: But how can i call a function with my button from my nodejs file? When i define the function loadScript() there, it is not defined.

Comment: You don't call the function. You make an HTTP request to the endpoint for the web service using Ajax. Then the server side code calls the function.

Comment: Do you have an example for how to do that? I´m really new on that area.

Comment: I refer you to the guides linked from the last paragraph of my answer.